# Почему адрес остаётся в памяти?

Tags: c++

Это нормально, что после удаления динамической переменной из памяти её адрес всё ещё можно получить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не совсем нормально, когда вы делаете скриншоты вместо кода

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют. изменить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 7):

Да, это нормально и даже разрешено.

В вашем случае, вы получаете адрес не удалённой памяти, а *указателя*, который вовсе не удалён. У вас `a` — лишь указатель на память, которую вы выделяете, и у него, как и у любой переменной, тоже есть адрес.

---

«Удалённая» переменная — `*a`. К ней вы, как ни странно, тоже смогли бы обратиться. (Но обращаться к удалённым переменным нельзя. Компилятор доверяет вам и не отслеживает эти обращения, так что они на вашей совести.)

Answer (score 2):

Вполне. Вот был метафорический развёрнутый ответ на эту тему (на английском):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Обычно после удаления динамической переменной рекомендуют обнулить указатель на неё, чтобы её адрес перестал быть доступным.